# Can the complement of the start sequence occur in a gene?

Tags: transcription, codon

Put another way, I suppose I'm wondering if the start sequence of a gene always actually starts a gene. If so, I assume it means that the complement of the start sequence in one strand would always start a gene in the other strand, but forcing some prefix of two genes to be complements of each other seems like it would make things a bit messy (but then again, when is biology ever not?).

I gather from [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/39273/77506) that this is more complicated than ATG (ie, AUG's complement's complement) occurring in the middle of the coding strand, but even if the start sequence is ATG + some other stuff (or rather, the other way around) it seems like the same problem with a longer sequence.

If not, then how is the start of a gene distinguished from a sequence that coincidentally happens to be the start sequence? One step further, how is that mechanism (which must not be part of the DNA sequence itself) reproduced?

Edit: After some snooping around it looks like the sort of "mess" I imagined can and does occur and is called "divergent gene overlap". So I guess the answer to the question I put in my title is ***yes***. (?)

Comment: (Disclaimer: In case it wasn't abundantly obvious, I'm very new to all this so apologies if this doesn't make sense and please let me know if there's context I'm missing I need to do some reading up on! Thanks!)

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! You have to differentiate between transcription and translation. Start codon has nothing to do with the initiation of transcription, it is the [promoter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_(genetics)).

Comment: Further to @Domen, please do some reading to clarify for yourself the start of a gene (DNA) — the promoter, specifing the start of its transcription to RNA; the start of the mRNA (which in eukaryotes is capped by a methylation sequence), and the start of the region translated into protein — the initiation codon (most frequently AUG). You will then realize that your question and title need clarification at the very least — "start sequence of a gene" has nothing to do with AUG (or ATG). Also, "complement" is  wrong — the complement of AUG is CAU. You mean same sequence on the opposite strand.